# how to implement method in JpaRepository(CrudRepository)

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, crud-repository

```
@Repository
interface TempRepository : JpaRepository<Temp, Int> {
  override fun findBySomethingId(id: Int): Optional<Temp>
}
```

Hi! I got problem with using JapRepositoy in Kotlin. as you know, Spring Data Jpa create query by interpreting method name. see code block above here. you can see method "findBySomethingId". spring jpa interpret that name and create "select * from temp where somthing_id = * ". but I want to implement that method manually. (I don't want spring to create query with method name"

```
@Repository
interface TempRepository : JpaRepository<Temp, Int> {
 override fun findBySomethingId(id: Int): Optional<Temp> {
   {...Implemetaion }
 }
}
```

but when I boot spring, I face error message "Failed to create query for method .."
and actually "something_id" column don't exist. but I have to that method name on my needs So I'am looking for some annotation to make 'jpa data' to create query depending on method's implementation instead depeding on method's name

what do I have to do. Thank you

Comment: Did you had a look at the readme? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior

Comment: thank you for answering It's great helpful